# Showing $\mathbb{E}(\max_{k \leq n}|X_k|)/\sqrt{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

If $(X_n: n \in \mathbb{N})$ is an identically distributed sequence in $\mathbb L^2(\mathbb{P})$, I want to show that

$$\displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{E}\left(\max\limits_{k \leq n}|X_k|\right)}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$$

as $n \to \infty$. Please could you advise me how to answer this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please consider updating your question with some information about what you have tried or where you are getting stuck. You will find people are much more willing to help if you do!

Comment: user113215 = user113211 = user113209?

Answer (score 2):

It's enough to show that if $(Y_k)$ is an identically distributed sequence in $\mathbb L^1(\mathbb P)$, then $\frac 1n\mathbb E\left(\max_{k\leqslant n}|Y_k|\right)\to 0$.

For a fixed $k$ and a fixed $R\gt 0$, write $Y_k=Y_k\chi_{\{|Y_k|\leqslant R\}}+Y_k\chi_{\{|Y_k|\gt R\}}$. Then 
$$\frac 1n\mathbb E\left(\max_{k\leqslant n}|Y_k|\right)\leqslant \frac Rn+\mathbb E[|Y_k|\chi_{\{|Y_k|\geqslant R\}}].$$

Comment: +1. Curious to see how the OP manages these indications, though.